# Change the value of a piece of content using a comment

Tags: 7, nodes, comments

I have a content type which I don't want a user to be able to edit once it has been created.  but I want them to be able to change 1 value and the way I want them to do that is through a selection box on a comment.  For example, on the content type there is a priority field.  When a user leaves a comment I have a selection box added to the comment with the same options.

How can I get that option box to sync with the option in the node itself?

Thanks

Kieran

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your content type is called `your_content_type` and your module is called `yourmodulename`, you can use the following code:

It will set some state when a none-priviledged user posts a comment, and show a state selection UI for priviledged users. The state will be saved to the CCK `field_erledigt_warten` in the node in either case.

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_comment().
 * Fill a CCK field  in Drupal 6
 */
function yourmodulename_comment(&$comment, $op) {
  global $user;

  if (is_array($comment)) {
    $node = node_load($comment['nid']);
  }
  else {
    $node = node_load($comment->nid);
  }

  if ($node->type == 'your_content_type') {
    switch ($op) {
      case 'insert':
      case 'update':
        if (user_access('edit field_erledigt_warten')) {
          // QD-Mitarbeiter
          if (isset($comment['field_erledigt_warten']) && $comment['field_erledigt_warten']) {
            if ($node->field_erledigt_warten[0]['value'] != $comment['field_erledigt_warten']) {
              $node->field_erledigt_warten[0]['value'] = $comment['field_erledigt_warten'];
              drupal_set_message(t('Status wurde auf %v ge&auml;ndert.', array('%v' => $comment['field_erledigt_warten'])));
              node_save($node);
            }
          }
        } else {
          // Kundenaccount
          $node->field_erledigt_warten[0]['value'] = 'neu';
          node_save($node);
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}

/**
    Implementation of hook_form_alter
 * Add a input box to the comment form
 */
function yourmodulename_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'comment_form') {
    if (is_array($form) && isset($form['nid']) && is_array($form['nid'])) {
      $node = node_load($form['nid']['#value']);
    }
    if (isset($node) && is_object($node) && isset($node->type) &&
      $node->type == 'your_content_type' && user_access('edit field_erledigt_warten')) {
      $states = array_flip(array('some', 'values', 'come', 'here'));
      foreach($states as $text=>$index) $states[$text] = $text;
      $status = $node->field_erledigt_warten[0]['value'];
      $form['field_erledigt_warten'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => 'neuer Status dieser Forumseite',
        '#default_value' => $status,
        '#options' => $states,
      );
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this the same for Drupal 7?

Comment: Very likely not. You'd have to go throu one of the many 'what has changed in D7' module update guides. So my code above can only serve as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

This was what the Comment Driven module was supposed to do, but they seem to have hit a wall in terms of a D7 version.

http://drupal.org/project/comment_driven